# Junit test run normally but fails with ecobertura - Wanted but not invoked appender.doAppend(<Capturing argument>);

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4, powermock, ecobertura

The following code:

```
@Mock
private Appender mockAppender;
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<LoggingEvent> captorLoggingEvent;
...
verify(mockAppender, atLeastOnce()).doAppend(captorLoggingEvent.capture());
```

run normally as JUnit test but fails using ecobertura with this message:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
appender.doAppend(<Capturing argument>);...Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

I'm using :

- Eclipse STS
- JRE(jdk1.6.0_41)
- junit-4.11.jar
- powermock-module-junit4-common-1.5.1.jar
- powermock-module-junit4-1.5.1.jar
- powermock-reflect-1.5.1.jar
- mockito-core-1.9.5.jar

Can you help me to solve this problem?